# How important to replace Furnace pressure switch with the one from the same manufacturer?

Tags: switch, furnace, pressure

We have 2004 Furnace American Standard and Nest thermostat.When I turn heat on the Nest it starts the furnace but no heat comes from the vents. We called one local company and tech person came, spent an hour diagnosing and said that it is a pressure switch that needs replacement.He said that it is important to have the switch from the same manufacturer but it takes 2 weeks just to get the part ( not even sure that during holidays it will be the case).
I have two questions:
1)is it Ok to replace the pressure switch with universal one?
2) does it make sense to ask another company to diagnose a problem? I read that power switch could be an indicator of another problem.
Thank you so much.
I have young kids and we are all freezing.
Inna

Comment: Can phone around to other local companies and see if they have the switch.  Unless the furnace company uses off the shelf(buy in stores) pressure switches, then you need to have one of theirs.

Comment: Have you verified that the pressure switch has *failed* as opposed to it is doing its job?  Blocked intake our exhaust vent, dirty or restricted air flow through burner, any open cover that should be closed, failure of inducer motor, condensate drain blocked or condensate trap empty?  Any of thee things might cause the pressure switch to trigger.   And of course, its own failure.  The model of your furnace, of the switch, and the furnace's manual would help us to answer whether you can buy generic parts.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the switch has the same frame (shape) and pressure setting it will be fine. The switch components are by a company that builds switches then stamped with a OEM number that only that manufacturer can purchase they add a large markup to the price but they are many times the same part so if they are physically the same with the same pressure points it makes n difference.